# Hatcher Exercise 3.1.11

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I am looking at the following question from Hatcher's Algebraic topology. I am trying to show that the quotient map q induces a non-trivial map of cohomology groups. I am having trouble seeing why the map in (a) from Z to Z/mZ is in fact surjective / how we deduce this from the cochain complex (2)? 
Thank you for any help you can give. 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure how (or even if) it follows from the celluar cochain complex.
However, the LES (long exact sequence) of the pair $\left(M,S^n\right)$ is:
$$ \cdots
\to H^{n+1}\left(M,S^n\right)
\overset{H^{n+1}\left(q\right)}{\to} H^{n+1}\left(M\right)
\overset{H^{n+1}\left(i\right)}{\to} H^{n+1}\left(S^n\right)
\to \cdots $$

Since $H^{n+1}\left(S^n\right)=0$, we know that $H^{n+1}\left(i\right)=0$, thus by exactness at the middle term:
$$ \mathrm{im}\left(H^{n+1}\left(q\right)\right)
= \ker\left(H^{n+1}\left(i\right)\right)
= \ker\left(0\right)
= H^{n+1}\left(M\right) $$

I.e. $H^{n+1}\left(q\right)$ is surjective.